# How to restore languages to Creality CR-6 SE after firmware update?

Tags: firmware, creality, creality-cr-6

I have been battling print issues since my purchase of a new Creality CR-6 SE. I chose to do a firmware upgrade to see if it's perhaps a patched issue. I used the [Creality Download page](https://www.creality.com/download) and downloaded the zip containing the 4.5.2 mainboard firmware for CR-6 SE.

I cleared an SD card and then put the .bin found/named (CR-6SE 32bit mainboard firmware\4.5.2mainboard (C & E version/CR-6SE - V1.0.2.bin)

It loaded and then I had no text.
I tried the next bin in the same folder, the same result... continued through all of them with the same result.

It appears that the other printer functions exist, I was able to run the bed leveling processes successfully, just no text is present to label anything or to indicate when it's working.

How do I get the text to return to my display?

Bonus: I navigated to the settings menu and clicked the language menu item (using icons to navigate) and then the printer UI freezes. I have to power cycle to interact with it again.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the UI of a CR-6 doesn't function correctly after a firmware upgrade, either the firmware upgrade didn't go well or the firmware of the screen is no longer compatible with the firmware of the printer.

If you know the screen and firmware are supposed to be compatible, try updating the firmware again. There is some sort of 'is this update the same as the current version' check on it, so you may have to alternate between different firmware files (.bin) or at least different filenames. Last time it took me 3 attempts.